# ¿Por qué no puedo hacer la encuesta anual de Stack Overflow desde mi país?

Tags: discusión, bug, encuesta-para-desarrolladores

Todos los años tomo parte en la encuesta de Stack Overflow para incluir mi opinión como programador. Desde hace años lo hago y aunque según las estadísticas no somos muchos haciéndolo creo que mi opinión cuenta también.

Este año 2019 ocurrió algo muy diferente:

> [image: acceso denegado]

Esto es:

> Access Denied.
>
> You don't have permission to access "http://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/..." on this server.
>
> Reference #18...

Entiendo que hay un embargo entre Cuba y Estados Unidos que puede llegar a producir estas situaciones, pero también entiendo que una encuesta difícilmente puede calificarse como "exportación de tecnología" ya que en realidad se clasifica como "recolección de datos".

Honestamente creo que es una situación lamentable y absurda que una situación política determinada, que para colmo de males no tiene nada que ver con mi opinión personal y la de otros en el tema, termine interfiriendo con el normal desarrollo de personas en esta comunidad ya que según tengo entendido el nuevo [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) especifica que:

> **No a la intolerancia.**
>
> No toleramos ninguna frase que pueda ofender o apartar a las personas por motivos de raza, sexo, orientación sexual o religión, y estos son solo algunos ejemplos. En caso de duda, simplemente no lo hagas.

Personalmente creo que debe tratarse de algún error honesto, no obstante pregunto:

¿Es este un comportamiento apropiado?

Comment: Un abrazo fuerte, qué enorme error que tú tengas que sufrir las consecuencias de esto.

Comment: Y es que tenga razón o no legalmente yo antes pude hacerlas, entonces estaba SO violando la ley antes? Evidentemente no es el caso, es una situación en extremo ridícula.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Según se desprende de [esta pregunta en Meta de Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379318/579895), al parecer la empresa usada para la encuesta, Qualtrics, ha bloqueado a los paises que sufren alguna sanción económica de USA, según se deduce de sus [condiciones de servicio](https://www.qualtrics.com/terms-of-service/)

Resumen:

> You warrant that you will not use the Services or Software in connection with any person, including yourself, that is (1) located in a country or region that is subject to comprehensive U.S. economic sanctions (including Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Syria, and the Crimea region of Ukraine); or (2) a designated, denied, or otherwise restricted party, as specified under the laws and regulations identified above.

Traducción.

> Usted garantiza que no usará los Servicios o el Software en relación con ninguna persona, incluido usted, que se encuentre en (1) un país o región que esté sujeto a sanciones económicas generales de EE. UU. (Incluidos Cuba, Irán, Corea del Norte, Siria, y la región de Crimea de Ucrania); o (2) una parte designada, denegada o restringida de otro modo, según se especifica en las leyes y regulaciones identificadas anteriormente.

---

> ¿Es este un comportamiento apropiado?

Explicada la razón técnica/legal, mi opinión personal es que como bien indicas, es irónico que al poco tiempo de aprobar el maravilloso [CoC (Código de conducta)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct), excluyan a partes enteras del mundo de la encuesta. Como dice el refranero, *Consejos vendo que para mi no tengo*.

Probablemente, este problema debería haberse previsto y solucionado antes de haber lanzado la encuesta.

Comment: Válido e igual, Slack bloqueó cuentas relacionadas de cualquier forma posible con Irán, Ucrania, Siria, etc. En este tipo de cosas, las empresas estadounidenses prefieren siempre pecar por exceso, descartando siempre a los usuarios del tercer mundo.

Answer (score 6):

Complementando la respuesta de @Pikoh

No soy experto en leyes pero creo que se trata de una omisión por parte del equipo de Stack Overflow que tomó la decisión de contratar a Qualtrics para hacer la encuesta. Espero que les sirva de experiencia en los años venideros. No obstante aquí les dejo un par de reflexiones:

El hecho que el Departamento del Tesoro de Estados Unidos embargue algunos países no significa que no pueda servirse contenido. Lo que no puede hacerse es, por ejemplo,  descargar software propietario. Esto último es "exportación de tecnología" y una clara violación a la ley. Esto en mi opinión sigue siendo injusto, por supuesto, pero las opiniones no tienen que ver con las leyes y estas deben cumplirse.

Aquí hay un par de ejemplos claros:

El buscador de Google funciona, sus servidores se encuentran en Estados Unidos.

[image: buscador de Google]

Google Developers por el contrario está bloqueado. Es lamentable pero completamente legal.

[image: Google Developers]

El hecho que sea ley tampoco significa que sea una buena ley y que esté bien concebida. Cosas absurdas ocurren todo el tiempo en materia de leyes, es por eso que estas se modifican todo el tiempo.

La parte en la que la opinión mundial debería acabar de ponerse de acuerdo es que este tipo de cosas afectan más a los ciudadanos comunes que a los gobiernos y el caso que nos ocupa es uno de los mejores ejemplos de ello. Emplear recursos en hacer valer una regulación que puede ser esquivada con una [RPN](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_privada_virtual) o VPN es un desperdicio de dichos recursos. Tengo fe que StackOverflow, uno de los sitios más inclusivos que conozco, no cometerá el mismo error nuevamente.

En cuanto a Qualtrics espero que se asesore mejor legalmente ya que es muy probable que termine perdiendo clientes por dicha decisión, no obstante les hice mi aporte directamente. Espero que sean receptivos.

[image: fin de la encuesta]

Comment: [Google Code](https://code.google.com) es otro espacio en el que aún se puede consultar:

Comment: @Rubén Sólo el Open Source, el developers y el code archive estan bloqueados así como un millón de servicios más como las tiendas de google, apple y microsoft, los servicios de advertising, etc.