# ¿Qué debe cambiar stackoverflow?, para bien

Tags: discusión

He estado leyendo varias preguntas preguntas sobre el tema. Y pregunto porque aun no se le ha dado solucion a estas cosas?
Por ejemplo

1. Una pregunta recompensa no puede ser otrogada la recompensa a mi mismo (aun cuando encontre la solucion al problema y es verificable esa solucion).
2. Muchas persona no son programadaores o estan aprendiendo o simplemente usan frecuentemente codigos de programacion pero no tienen un conocimiento tan amplio. Es necesario ajustar un sistema de recompensa a esas personas por su contribucion al sitio?
3. Hay que recompensar mas a esas personas que arduamente ayudan a los demas a dar solucion a sus errores? Se deberia implementar un nuevo sistema de incentivo en el sitio?
4. Otra cosa la medalla Nuestra medalla "No soy un robot" . Ya no esta disponible? Creo que desde 2017. Porque esto dejo de realizarse. Ese era un espacio fundamental para socializar mas alla de etiquetas, he incluso me atrevo a decir que hasta colaboraciones mas alla de stack.
5. Votos negativos a nuevos usuarios. Creen que otorgar muchos votos negativos a una {mala pregunta} es ejemplarizante y en realidad ayuda a mejorar el contenido?
6. Encuesta anual de Stack Overflow desde mi país? Muchos paises estan bloqueados. por ejmplo mi pais (Cuba).
   Que opinan de esto?

Comment: No se entiende lo que dices. Es algo relacionado con preguntas con recompensa, pero no logro desentrañar su contenido.

Comment: no se pueden otorgar recompensas a los **comentarios** no se de donde sacas esto... y para que se otorgue automáticamente una recompensa existen criterios que deben cumplirse como haber obtenido un mínimo de votos positivos. por lo cual si una respuesta es mala o mal intencionada, fácilmente puedes reportarla o meterle tu voto negativo...

Comment: Entiendo poco de lo que expones, ¿puedes mejorar la redacción por favor?

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que dices: 1.¿Autorecompensarse? 2.¿Crear recomenpensas para los que no son programadores? 3.Uno ayuda porque quiere sin recibir nada a cambio (Desconozco si ya existe un sistema de recomenpensas para esas personas) 4.Es un tema para hablar con los grandes. 5. El voto negativo se da por una simple razon "La pregunta no es util" 6.Otro tema para hablar con los grandes

Comment: Entonces hay que plantear cada pregunta por separado?, Lo del tema del pais porque no poner la encuesta en otro sistema mas inclusivo? Todo por politica de los dirigientes que para nada involucra a las personas. Entonces no es viable este tipo de preguntas?

Comment: El objetivo de mi pregunta es solo crear una comunidad mas inclusiva y dinamica. En meta hay muchas preguntas con respuesta valida pero que al final aun no se han resuelto.

Comment: @BetaM en meta las reglas son mas flexibles.. puede preguntar todo esto.. si esta relacionado al mismo tema... cosa que no es asi... pero bue..

Answer (score 11):

Todas las comunidades tienen margen de mejora y la red de StackExchange no se salva de eso. Tus sugerencias son interesantes, pero se escapan del alcance del sitio de StackOverflow en Español, y quizás deberían plantearse a un nivel más alto (como [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)) porque, aunque lleguemos a un acuerdo, no tenemos poder para realizar ciertos cambios unilateralmente.

Voy a intentar abordar todas las cuestiones (son bastantes):

> 1. Una pregunta recompensa no puede ser otrogada la recompensa a mi mismo (aun cuando encontre la solucion al problema y es verificable esa solucion).

**Esto funciona así a propósito y no creo que sea algo que se vaya a cambiar**. Imagina si se permitiese que una persona se auto-recompensanse: mucha gente espabilada recibiría respuestas que les valiesen, pero en lugar de dar la recompensa, escribirían una respuesta (basándose en las otras) y se darían la recompensa a sí mismos.

Una pregunta con recompensa recibe un lugar privilegiado en el sitio (aparece en la sección de destacadas), donde es más visible y recibe más atención por parte de los usuarios. Permitir auto-recompensas podría fácilmente cambiar la dinámica del sitio para peor.

¿Es injusto para usuarios que encuentran su propia solución? Sí. Pero, en general, el sistema es más justo y funciona mejor así.

> 2. Muchas persona no son programadaores o estan aprendiendo o simplemente usan frecuentemente codigos de programacion pero no tienen un conocimiento tan amplio. Es necesario ajustar un sistema de recompensa a esas personas por su contribucion al sitio?

**No, las reglas deben ser iguales para todos** y el sistema de recompensas no debe ajustarse al tipo de usuario. Independientemente de cómo quieras ajustar el sistema de recompensas (no termina de quedar claro en la pregunta).

Principalmente, porque es casi imposible saber si los usuarios son avanzados o estudiantes, o si su conocimiento es amplio o limitado. El único modo sería si ellos mismos proporcionan una respuesta, lo que la hace no fiable por defecto. Lo más seguro es que el sistema acabase degradándose debido a cuentas secundarias (sock puppets).

> 3. Hay que recompensar mas a esas personas que arduamente ayudan a los demas a dar solucion a sus errores? Se deberia implementar un nuevo sistema de incentivo en el sitio?

**Esto es posible ya que el sistema ya existe**. Los usuarios pueden crear recompensas en preguntas que no son suyas y uno de los motivos para crear una recompensa es para premiar una respuesta excelente.

Si una persona trabaja arduamente para dar buenas respuestas y soluciones, cualquier usuario del sitio que puede crear y darle una recompensa (o varias) y de ese modo premiar las contribuciones excepcionales.

...pero cuidado: si le das muchas recompensas a otro usuario, eso hará que salten las alarmas en la zona de moderadores y se investiguen las cuentas. Muchas veces, cuando algo así ocurre es por cuentas secundarias.

> 4. Otra cosa la medalla Nuestra medalla "No soy un robot" . Ya no esta disponible? Creo que desde 2017. Porque esto dejo de realizarse. Ese era un espacio fundamental para socializar mas alla de etiquetas, he incluso me atrevo a decir que hasta colaboraciones mas alla de stack.

**La medalla "No soy un robot" sigue estando disponible** y se han realizado eventos en las que 33 usuarios la han conseguido (si no recuerdo mal, en Argentina, España y México).

Estoy de acuerdo con que esos eventos son importantes (normalmente son más bien pequeños *meetups*) y una manera genial de socializarse y poner cara a usuarios que antes solo se conocía por nombre... pero, dadas las circunstancias actuales, es imposible organizar eventos en persona (y parece que va para largo).

Pero los eventos volverán y la medalla de "No soy un robot" será otorgada nuevamente. Es cuestión de tiempo :)

> 5. Votos negativos a nuevos usuarios. Creen que otorgar muchos votos negativos a una {mala pregunta} es ejemplarizante y en realidad ayuda a mejorar el contenido?

Respondo a título personal y no como moderador: **una mala pregunta debe tener votos negativos**. No importa que sea una pregunta de un usuario nuevo o de un usuario con amplia experiencia en el sitio. Si se permite el mal contenido por ser de un usuario nuevo, se abre la puerta a que el sitio se llene de mal contenido.

StackOverflow es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Las malas preguntas atraen malas respuestas, son un cáncer para el sitio y deben atajarse lo antes posible. Al mismo tiempo, queremos que los usuarios (y especialmente los nuevos) se sientan bienvenidos y cómodos en el sitio. El tema de las preguntas malas por parte de usuarios nuevos es bastante complejo y delicado.

Personalmente, creo que cada situación debe afrontarse teniendo en cuenta las circunstancias: si veo una pregunta mala de un usuario con experiencia, dejo un voto negativo y un comentario; si la pregunta mala es de un usuario nuevo, normalmente dejo un comentario y espero. Si después de un tiempo (1 semana) no ha habido cambios, entonces seguramente vote negativo.

> 6. Encuesta anual de Stack Overflow desde mi país? Muchos paises estan bloqueados. por ejmplo mi pais (Cuba). Que opinan de esto?

**Esto es un tema legal que va más allá de StackOverflow**. Tiene que ver con los Estados Unidos (donde StackOverflow tiene su sede) y las leyes del país que prohíben tener intercambios de propiedad intelectual con naciones bajo sanción o embargo (p.e. Cuba, Irán, Corea del Norte, etc.)

[Este tema ya se trató en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3878/250) y los usuarios proporcionaron buenas respuestas y enlaces que explican mejor la situación de lo que yo lo explicaré en dos párrafos.

Comment: No añadiría ni una coma a tu respuesta Alvaro. Excelente.